# Calculating/estimating carbon content in soil by using Remote Sensing

Tags: remote-sensing

I am analysing sugar cane crops with QGIS and need to estimate the soil carbon content to evaluate the nutrition status of the crops. 
The problem is that I don't have ground data so there is no possibility of doing any calibration. The only available data that I have is the shapefile with all the crops mapped as polygons and the NDVI and NDMI calculated previously.
I am wondering whether I can get this info through Remote Sensing (by using either Sentinel-1 SAR data or Sentinel-2).

Comment: Please be more specific when asking a question, we neither know your available assets, nor which software you're using, nor which data you have, etc.

Comment: Is soil nutrition just based on carbon content of the soil?  Won't you also need to know underlying geology?